# Get variable data from subprocess continuously

Tags: python, subprocess, speech-to-text

I have a subprocess that constantly listens to the microphone, converts the audio to text and stores the result. The code for this is

```
from os import environ, path
import pyaudio
from utils import micStream
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "PATH TO MODEL"

config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/acoustic-model'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/language-model.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/language-dictionary.dict'))
config.set_string('-logfn', 'nul')
decoder = Decoder(config)

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
stream.start_stream() 

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print(decoder.hyp().hypstr.lower())

                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

I am trying to run this as a subprocess and have the parent read the string `decoder.hyp().hypstr.lower()` continuously without blocking the rest of the main process. I've tried

`subprocess.check_output()`
and
`listener=subprocess.Popen([sys.executable,'file_name'])`

But both seem to block my code. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can get the data shipped more quickly by adding `sys.stdout.flush()` after the print, but your parent is going to block until something gets sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue          # ADD IMPORT

from os import environ, path
import pyaudio
from utils import micStream
from pocketsphinx.pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase.sphinxbase import *


def get_audio(q):
    MODELDIR = "PATH TO MODEL"

    config = Decoder.default_config()
    config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/acoustic-model'))
    config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/language-model.lm.bin'))
    config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us/language-dictionary.dict'))
    config.set_string('-logfn', 'nul')
    decoder = Decoder(config)

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=16000, input=True, frames_per_buffer=1024)
    stream.start_stream()

    in_speech_bf = False
    decoder.start_utt()
    while True:
        buf = stream.read(1024)
        if buf:
            decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
            if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
                in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
                if not in_speech_bf:
                    decoder.end_utt()
                    q.put(decoder.hyp().hypstr.lower())    # PUT THE OUTPUT INTO QUEUE
                    decoder.start_utt()
        else:
            break
    decoder.end_utt()

out_q = Queue()
audio_p = Process(target=get_audio, args=(out_q,))
audio_p.start()

while True:
    # If data has been received process it
    if not out_q.empty():
        res = out_q.get()
        # Perform whatever needs to happen when the parent receives the output here
    # After processing the data, or if no data has been received
    # Put the code that needs to run in the main process here
```